# HTTPS request working on Postman but not in my python script with requests

Tags: python, http, https, python-requests, postman

I'm currently trying to scrape data from a website, I know I need to add "User-Agent" and "Accept" to my header to make it work.

That's what I did on postman in a first place to get my request right and it worked.

[Postman screenshot]

[image: 1]

[HTTP raw request from postman]

[image: 2]

But when I try it on my Python code, I keep getting 403 errors, even by using generated code from postman. I really don't understand what I'm missing to make it work.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.leboncoin.fr/recherche?text=test"

payload={}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36A',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

This is the code generated by postman for my requests and it keeps getting 403 error.

The request is exactly the same as postman one, I really don't get it.

Comment: Maybe you mean `requests.get(...)`

Comment: i tried both versions, this one is what postman gave me, but i also tried with requests.get and i got the same result

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem using the code you posted. It seems to be working fine. Maybe share the errors you are getting as well.

Comment: i am getting an alternative html page which isn't the one i'm looking for and the response.status_code is 403

Comment: perhaps the website has decided you're scraping and blocked you. Have you read the html page?

Comment: there's a cross-verification with `geo.captcha-delivery.com` those are a pain. you'd better go with selenium

Comment: @balmy I thought about it, but in that case, postman request should not be working too. the HTML page is an alternative page saying  me to go to the website. That's the page i get if i don't add the "User_Agent" and the "Accept" in the header

Comment: @diggusbickus I never tried selenium, i'll give it a try. But i don't understand why postman request worked in that case

Comment: Try looking into @balmy's suggestions too. I just reproduced the 403s after about 30 requests per second.

Comment: i got 403 at first try

Comment: I finally realised that the problem comes from a capchat, i have no idea why postman wasn't getting it, but now it does and the page is a capchat. I don't know how i'll pass it but at least i know why it didn't worked thx to all of you